# People picker query to get user and its role

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, permissions

People picker are working perfectly in sharepoint 2013, but in check permission, it shows only user login name and not show user role [sharepoint analyst or ...].

What can I do now?

Comment: Whether users in the windows authentication or other authentication methods?

Comment: I am searching user away from the farm server. Authentication : claim based authentication and user information list have user and its role.